# Remove rows with same ID from two lists in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a list of objects called `checkins` that lists all the times a user has checked into something and another set of objects called `flagged_checkins` that is certain checkins that the user has flagged. They both reference a 3rd table called with a `location_id`

I'd like to take the two lists of objects, and remove any of the `checkins` which have a location_id in `flagged_checkins`

How do I compare these sets and remove the rows from 'checkins'

Comment: Two questions:

1. Are both belonging to the same model?

2. Is flagged_checkins definitely a subset of checkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523282/django-in-not-in-query),

```
checkins.objects.filter( location_id__in = list(flagged_checkins.objects.values_list('location_id', flat=True)) ).delete()
```

Comment: But this would remove the objects at the database level as well.

Comment: Well, I'll remove the .delete() and try it

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a `queryset` then, you can definitely try:

```
checkins.objects.exclude( location_id__in = list(flagged_checkins.objects.values_list('location_id', flat=True)) )
```

This would remove the objects based on your criteria. But not from the db level.