# exclude a query result in another query

Tags: django, python-2.7

Here i want to do is that ,i want to list all the person who didn't blocked me.Here in the table **`Blocked`** there is two columns name
**`who`** and **`whose`** . In **`whose`** column i store the id of the person whom i blocked and in the **`who`** column i store my id. Now i want to do that, when the blocked person  click on
**view-person** button in my web page he cannot see  profile of the person one who blocked him.

when i did this query **`blocked_list = Blocked.objects.filter(whose = user_id)`**. Now i got the list of the persons who blocked me. Now i want to exclude all this person from this query **`total_profiles = persons.objects.all().exclude(blocked_list)`**.  How can i do this.

**models.py**

```
class persons(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class blocked(models.Model):
    who = models.ForeignKey(persons)
    whose = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def blocked(request): 
    blocked_list = Blocked.objects.filter(whose = user_id) 
    total_profiles = persons.objects.all().exclude(blocked_list)
    return render_to_response('profiles/view_all.html', {'total_profiles':total_profiles,'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request),)
```

please correct the question if it is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
total_profiles = persons.objects.all().exclude(id__in = blocked_list.values_list('id', flat=True))
```

It's untested, but adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523282/django-in-not-in-query).

Some notes:

- if `persons` has the default manager, you can omit `all()`.
- `whose` does not have an index, so it will become slow when your dataset gets big. You can use a `ForeignKey` field instead of an `IntegerField`
- the common convention is to capitalize class names and to write model names in singular i.e. `Person` instead of `persons`

Comment: How it will become slow , when dataset gets big.If you don't mind could you please explain because i am new to django and python.thanks@Daniel Hepper

Comment: This is not really specific to Django. By default, an `IntegerField` does not have an index. Therefor the database has to compare `user_id` to all rows in the `blocked` table. That becomes slow when your dataset gets big (millions of rows).

Comment: Ok.thanks a lot for your answer.Let me ask one more thing. If i make that whose column as a ForeignKey of User,How can i skip that database comparison.@Daniel Hepper

Comment: Django automatically creates an index for a `ForeignKey` field.