# Get Records from Referenced Table "Minus" All The Records referenced from the Referencing Table

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model A that has a foreign Key to the User Model (current_user_id).

User.objects.filter() gives me all users.

How can i add an additional exclude to find all the User objects that are not currently referenced in A?

For Example

```
Users
=====
1
2
3

A
===
id current_user_id
1      1
2
3
```

I want to get only Users with id 2 and 3 (And not 1 because it is referenced in A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with the following straightforward approach:

```
User.objects.exclude(pk__in=A.objects.values_list('current_user_id', flat=True))
```

`A.objects.values_list('current_user_id', flat=True)` returns a list of `User` model primary keys that are referenced by the `A` model. `User.objects.exclude(pk__in=...)` helps to get all other users.

In other words, this expression returns all users that are not related to `A`.

Also see:

- [Django in / not in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523282/django-in-not-in-query)
- [`exclude()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude)
- [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [**Django docs** on Many-to-one Relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships). In the "**Querying in the opposite direction**" example, you can see that within the filter you can access the related object.

In your example, you can get all User records without a related A object with the query:

`User.objects.filter(a__isnull=True)`

In the case of one-to-many ForeignKeys, I typically specify the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) argument as the plural version of the model name. It helps to make the one-to-many relationship clearer.

In your example it would look like this:

```
class User(models.Model)
    pass

class A(models.Model):
    current_user_id = ForeignKey(User, related_name='as')

# now the above query would look like this:
User.objects.filter(as__isnull=True)
```

It helps clarify which model is the one and which model is the many in the one-to-many relationship.