# How to list all the groups that a user does not belong to in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

I am new to django and have recently started working on it.
I have made a django application and I am able to make the user log into it and display the group that he is a member of using:

```
request.user.groups.all()
```

Now, I want to display those groups, in which he is not a member, on a web page, upon his login, so that he can click on a link associated with that group and get himself registered. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question: [Django in / not in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523282/django-in-not-in-query)
So it should be like this:

```
Group.objects.exclude(id__in=request.user.groups.all().values_list('id', flat=True))
```